# i am getting the error in truffle but in online compiler(remix)there is not showing any error in this keyword and selfdestruct function

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, cryptocurrency

TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from contract spsTokenSale to address requested.
require(tokenContract.balanceOf(this)>= _numberOfTokens);

Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested.
selfdestruct(admin);

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide code for better understanding. May be you have not declared address 'payable' that's why you are facing this "Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested" issue.

As in latest version of solidity you must declare address also as payable if it will be receiving/transferring ethers.

If the issue is in truffle not in remix you can check for the version of solidity in truffle box. As it's most likely version mismatch issue.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the solution to this question in another forum. The compiler requires you to explicitly declare the type of the token address.

Instead of using `tokenContract.balanceOf(this)`, change it to `tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))`.

Refer to this link for more details - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64868/typeerror-invalid-type-for-argument-in-function-call-invalid-implicit-conversi/64869

Answer (score 0):

If you are using solidity version > 7 then your syntex is not    correct.Use ***address(this)*** if you want to access your       contract address  & use ***selfdestruct(payable(admin));*** if you       want to destroy your smart contract .

```
require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))>= _numberOfTokens);
selfdestruct(payable(admin));
```